# How can I print the distance between 2 cities, given their latitude and longitude

Tags: java

I started my program like this:

```
 public static void main( String[] args )
         {
   if(args.length < 2)
   {
   System.err.println("Usage: java -jar lab5.jar infile outfile");
   System.exit(99);
   }

   Cruncher dataManipulator = new Cruncher(args[0], args[1]);

   dataManipulator.openFiles();
   dataManipulator.findDistance();
   dataManipulator.writeRecords();
   dataManipulator.closeFiles();
 }
  String oneCity = "British Columbia:Vancouver:49Â° 17' N:123Â° 8' W";
        String twoCity = "Ontario:Hamilton:43Â° 15' N:79Â° 52' W";
        String[] source;
        String[] rawLatitude;
        String[] rawLongitude;
        int sourceLatDegrees;
        int sourceLatMinutes;

        if(twoCity.matches("Ontario:Hamilton.*")){
                source = twoCity.split(":");
                for(String inspect: source){
                        System.out.printf("%s\n", inspect);
                }
                rawLatitude = source[2].split("\\D+");
                for(String inspect: rawLatitude){
                     System.out.printf("%s\n", inspect);
                }
                sourceLatDegrees = Integer.parseInt(rawLatitude[0]);
                sourceLatMinutes = Integer.parseInt(rawLatitude[1]);
                System.out.printf("source lat degrees %d source lat minutes %d\n", 
                        sourceLatDegrees, sourceLatMinutes);
        }

         double earthRadius = 6371;   // in km
         double distance = Math.acos(Math.sin(Lat1) * Math.sin(Lat2) + 
                 Math.cos(Lat1) * Math.cos(Lat2) *
                 Math.cos(Long2 - Long1)) * earthRadius;

         public static double rad2deg(double rad) {

  return (rad * 180.0 / Math.PI);

} 

 }
```

I need to show an output that will prompt the user for two city and province names. It will print a message to the screen stating the distance between the two cities in kms.If one of the cities is not found in the file you will write an error message to the screen stating which city was not found and silently end the program.If the user inputs the same city and province name twice then your program should do something polite and sensible. Can someone help me print the Some of this code? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

From https://www.geodatasource.com/developers/java

```
class DistanceCalculator
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        System.out.println(distance(32.9697, -96.80322, 29.46786, -98.53506, "M") + " Miles\n");
        System.out.println(distance(32.9697, -96.80322, 29.46786, -98.53506, "K") + " Kilometers\n");
        System.out.println(distance(32.9697, -96.80322, 29.46786, -98.53506, "N") + " Nautical Miles\n");
    }

    private static double distance(double lat1, double lon1, double lat2, double lon2, String unit) {
        double theta = lon1 - lon2;
        double dist = Math.sin(deg2rad(lat1)) * Math.sin(deg2rad(lat2)) + Math.cos(deg2rad(lat1)) * Math.cos(deg2rad(lat2)) * Math.cos(deg2rad(theta));
        dist = Math.acos(dist);
        dist = rad2deg(dist);
        dist = dist * 60 * 1.1515;
        if (unit == "K") {
            dist = dist * 1.609344;
        } else if (unit == "N") {
            dist = dist * 0.8684;
        }

        return (dist);
    }


    private static double deg2rad(double deg) {
        return (deg * Math.PI / 180.0);
    }


    private static double rad2deg(double rad) {
        return (rad * 180 / Math.PI);
    }
}
```